# Typescript get object keys whose value is string

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to get the keys of an object whose values are string? I have an object `MyType` like:

```
type SomeObjectType = {
    a: number;
    b: string;
};

type MyType = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: number;
    d: SomeObjectType;
};
```

Expected result `"a" | "b"`:

```
type Test = OnlyStringKeys<MyType, keyof MyType>; // "a" | "b"
```

My try:

```
type OnlyStringKeys<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends string ? K : never;
type Test = OnlyStringKeys<MyType, keyof MyType>; // never
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgeQEYCsIGNgBVzQC8UA3gFBSVQCGAXFAHYCuCqEATgNwVWr0DOwdgEsGAc24BfbmVCQoAWRD55xclRoChoiT0p8ogkeO4as9Zqw6mqAE3rwkaTDhUQpMudGQMANiBhtcQBpCBB+AB5cABooYKgIAA9gCAZbfigAazC4ADMoXAA+KGJcAG1ggF0E5NT0wyCxKAB+OKgLCAA3azJZAgKIQRKoH39A4zFQ8IilN1jskDzFZQJCziA)